# What reasons that ThreeJS DracoLoader works in Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, firefox, three.js, arraybuffer

I am trying to load some Draco `.drc` files on my macOS desktop browser using ThreeJS in an SPA with Vue/Node. It works fine on the latest versions of Chrome, but not so for at least up to the last 20 major versions of Firefox. I am using this [DracoLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/d3bff25fc38c6143665b7ef482f2ebef3073b3af/examples/js/loaders/DRACOLoader.js) What are some reasons why this could happen given the following:

1) Error in console on Firefox:

```
THREE.DRACOLoader: Decoding failed: Not a Draco file.
uncaught exception: Object 2
Error: THREE.DRACOLoader: Unexpected geometry type. b0bd052f-2408-3e4c-89f8-1394c532b72f:167:21
    onmessage blob:http://localhost:8080/b0bd052f-2408-3e4c-89f8-1394c532b72f:167
```

2) Using the same encoder and decoder versions as described here:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14552#issuecomment-407977068

3) Using the same ThreeJS version and loader version in the examples folder as described in last paragraph here:
https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Import-via-modules

4) Seeing that the first place I’ve seen it deviating at is at this￼ `buffer`￼ variable￼https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/DRACOLoader.js#115
The bytelength is smaller in the Firefox case. Not sure how that part in Firefox right now. However, according to the docs for FileLoader, the cache is supposed to be enabled, which I’ve found to not be the case. But even so, the same error occurs. When I console log them out, interestingly the Firefox case shows them out of size order too.

Firefox:
    the buffer is 
    ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 2099 }
    the buffer is 
    ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 552798 }
    the buffer is 
    ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 4527 }
    the buffer is 
    ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 12079 }
    the buffer is 
    ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 72493 }

Chrome:

```
the buffer is ArrayBuffer(2347) {}
the buffer is ArrayBuffer(4504) {}
the buffer is ArrayBuffer(12058) {}
the buffer is ArrayBuffer(72755) {}
the buffer is ArrayBuffer(554327) {}
```

5) I've imported the latest polyfills from `core-js`

6) The `.drc` being requested over the network for decoding seems to be the same with the same `content-length`